# Bing Maps API v8 mutipolyline (multiple segment line) support?

Tags: bing-maps

I have several hours trying to find information about support of multipolylines (or multiple segment lines) on Bing Maps API v8, to no avail. I need to have lines made of several segments, in the same way sql server supports it, i.e.

```
geography::STMLineFromText ('MULTILINESTRING((-84.6725847 31.7707373, -84.6556331 31.7698178)(-93.3023304 33.9048702, -93.3022956 33.9048486))', 4326)
```

Here, SQL constructs a line made of 2 separate segments.

Leaflet support multipolylines via several arrays of lat/lngs inside an array. i.e. (illustrative purposes)

```
var polyline = L.polyline([[31.7707373 -84.6725847,31.7698178 -84.6556331] [33.9048702 -93.3023304, 33.9048486 -93.3022956]], { color: 'red', interactive: true, bubblingMouseEvents: false })
```

How can achieve this under Bing Maps API v8? ideas/suggestions are welcomed!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use MultiLineString's in Bing Maps. If your data is in Well Known Text format, there is a module for that in Bing Maps. Here is a sample: https://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#WKT_Read_Write_Paste (looks like you have to pan/zoom the map to the area of the shape in this sample, but trying your MultiLineString in this sample, it did render).

Here is a code block:

```
//Load the Well Known Text module.
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.WellKnownText', function () {
    //Parse well known text string.
    var line = Microsoft.Maps.WellKnownText.read('MULTILINESTRING((-84.6725847 31.7707373, -84.6556331 31.7698178)(-93.3023304 33.9048702, -93.3022956 33.9048486))');

    //Add parsed shape to the map.
    map.entities.push(line);
});
```

Comment: Pasting the multilinestring on the bingmapsv8samples website draws an straight line starting in the middle of Arkansas and the other end in Georgia... Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: That's because one line is several hundred miles long and the other is one mile long. You can't see the smaller one until you zoom in really close. Zoom into the end of the line in Georgia and you will see the second line.

Comment: You are right. Zooming shown the additional segment. Are you aware if the Bing Maps API dev team have planned to expand the support of those multiple segment lines when you construct a line using the Microsoft.Maps.Polyline? (like leaflet does with their L.polyline that accepts an array of sub lat/lng arrays)

Comment: A don't know the Bing Maps teams plans. I'm on the Azure Maps team. The Azure Maps Web SDK fully supports Multi-geometry shapes by default. Here are some details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-add-line-layer Here are more samples of Azure Maps: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net The main page for Azure Maps is here: https://azure.com/maps

Comment: I tried on the Bing Maps dev portal (https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk), on the section Data Modules/Well Known Text Module and it worked too.